# Fill a column based on levels of first column and condition on second column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

We have a data frame, df, with two columns as given below. Variable A has two levels, 1 and 2. Variable B has three levels YES, NO, and OTHER. We want to derive another data frame, df2, with **variable C, which takes a value of** **"1"** **if there exists at least one YES for any level in variable A** **, otherwise "0".**

**df**

```
A   B
1   YES
1   YES
1   OTHER
1   NO
1   YES
1   NO
2   YES
2   YES
2   YES
2   NO
2   YES
3   OTHER
3   NO
3   NO
3   NO
```

**df2**

```
A   C
1   1
2   1
3   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> df['B'].eq('YES').groupby(df['A']).any().astype(int).reset_index(name='C')
   A  C
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert column `B` into numbers, using a defaultdict, and after, group by on `A` to get the max:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d['YES'] = 1
df.assign(B = df.B.map(d)).groupby('A', as_index = False).agg(C=('B', 'max'))

   A  C
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  0
```